# TFS no agent could be found with the following capabilities svn, Xamarin.iOS

Tags: svn, xamarin, tfs

Hi I have installed TFS2017 for a Xamarin(forms) Project to Test and Build for Ios.

I have Installed Visual Studio 2015 on the same machine as the TFS.
My version management is a local SVN server.

When I want to start my Xamarin.Ios Build it shows the Message

> no agent could be found with the following capabilities: svn,
>   Xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have two problems:

1. You don't have SubVersion installed (commandline) and in the path environment variable of the service user or system.
2. You need to install Xamarin on a Mac in order to build a mac, as documented here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/xamarin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
But i have some points to add.
1. I Installed Tortoise SVN (wich in standard setup settings not installing the commandline tools) so i had to reinstall them.
2. You also need to install a **TFS Build agent on the mac**